# How to change a colour of a JButton on Intellij idea

Tags: java

I wrote some code for a simple calculator. Let me explain; the calculator performs only four operations: addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.
I wanted to design a program so that when I press a key on the calculator well it changes color from white to the color chosen by the programmer (i.e. me); but the code that I wrote to change key color was not accepted by the IDE and it generated heaps of errors. Here is the code I had chosen to change a color of JButton.

```java
if ((Screen.getText(buttonTwoText)).equals(true)) {

  buttonTwo.getcolorModel("red");

  Thread.sleep(millis:2000);

  buttonTwo.getColorModel("white");
}

//Screen here is my JTextField name , ButtonTwo is a one of my JButtons name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JComponent (JButton) has two methods for changing the background and foreground colors.

```
button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

You can use any Color instances that you want.

Comment: @Gouneken if your questions are being answered, you should mark them as answered.  If the answers are appear worthwhile to you, you should upvote them.